# Парсер с помощью CURL и phpQuery, активировать кнопку

Tags: php, парсер, curl, phpquery

На странице во время парсинга, необходимо нажать кнопку "Показать больше". При нажатии на эту кнопку, появляются скрытые елементы div, сама же кнопка пропадает со страници (остается только div, в котором она находиться). Пробовал вот таким методом:

```
$but = $activate_but->find('button')->trigger('click');
$but = $activate_but->find('button')->trigger('submit');
$but = $activate_but->find('button')->submit();
```

Возможно есть какой то другой способ, благодарю!

Comment: скорее всего этот контент появляется через ajax запрос при нажатии на кнопку. найдите url, по которому  делается запрос и каким методом. потом обратитесь туда через curl.

Comment: @МаксМаксимус, я правильно понимаю, эта ссылка должна появиться в Networks при просмотре через F12?

Comment: другой способ определенно есть. а вот то что у вас написано это не способ. ваш парсер это не эмулятор браузера и действий пользователя, это библиотека которая разбирает текст. она не может нажимать какие-то кнопки или что-то еще делать. это просто обработчик текста. Если вы хотите подгрузиь данные, которые в реальности появляются на странице после клика, то разберитесь в браузере, что происходит при нажатии кнопки. Куда и какие запросы отправляются, и какие еще действия происходят. а потом эти запросы эмулируйте и получайте ответ.

Comment: да, верно. исследуйте с помощью инструментов разработчика. В Networks должны появится ресуры на которые делаются запросы. так же посмотрите, какие параметры передаются для того чтоб получить ответ и каким методом

Comment: @МаксМаксимус, если у Вас есть минутка, помогите пожалуйста. Одна из страниц сайта - https://versus.com/en/canon-pixma-mx870
Там ниже есть General Info, и та самая заветная кнопочка Show More

Comment: @teran, если у Вас есть минутка, помогите пожалуйста. Одна из страниц сайта - https://versus.com/en/canon-pixma-mx870
Там ниже есть General Info, и та самая заветная кнопочка Show More

Comment: так там по клику на эту кнопку идет простой редирект на страницу с определенными товарами. вот вы эту страницу и должны парсить.

Comment: @МаксМаксимус, можно пожалуйста по подробнее, на какую страницу именно? И там есть другие кнопки Show More+, они так само переходят на эту страницу?

Comment: https://versus.com/en/all-in-one-printer?filter[]=print_resolution=21127500,23040000

Comment: @МаксМаксимус, это не так кнопка. Еще ниже есть блоки General Info, Print Quality, и там есть кнопка Показать больше

Comment: обратите внимание на блок `<script id="reactInitData">`  в коде страницы. данные там лежат все.

Comment: если вы говорите про раздел Print quality и кнопку в нем "SHOW MORE SPECS +", то эти данные получаются из json, который записан в window.__data= ... . берите нужную часть html страницы и парсите ее как json, получите нужный контент

Comment: @teran, то ли я слепой, но нету на странице такого скрипта...

Comment: @МаксМаксимус, а можете рассказать подробнее, как это сделать? Я просто правда не понимаю...

Comment: смотрите лучше. есть там такой блок. внутри json, в нем ваши данные лежат.

Comment: @teran, Вы уверены что именно такой скрипт? Я просто правда не вижу такого, пересмотрел абсолютно все блоки, такого нету...

Comment: не надо смотреть, надо открыть код страницы и искать поиском указанную фразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот нужный вам объект выделен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получайте содержимое всей страницы с помощью curl. далее получаете содержимое `<script id="reactInitData">` и обрабатывайте как json.

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам!